# Swiper and FullpageJS scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, swiper.js

I've got a little problem with those two. I'm using FullpageJS for my whole page scrolling and Swiper in one section.

My page contains 3 sections:

1. Intro section with some text and main menu
2. Products section where I've put Swiper

3.End section with contact form and footer.

FullpageJS is ofc scrolling only between these.

There's my swiper code:

```
let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        // Optional parameters
        releaseOnEdges: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        loop:false,
        centeredSlides: true,
        breakpoints:{
           768:{
               direction:'horizontal',
               slidesPerView: '1.1'
           }
        },
        slidesPerView: '1.65',
        mousewheel: {
            invert: false,
            releaseOnEdges:true,
        }
    });
```

As you can see swiper is controlled by mouse scroll.
There's my fullpageJS code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    controlArrows: false,
    normalScrollElements: '#products',
});
```

"normalScrollElements" prevents fullpageJS from scrolling when #products section is on screen.

The problem that I'm facing is Swiper method 'isEnd' executes too fast. Products section contains full width and full height Swiper container with 10 slides.

What I want to do is to tell Swiper to slide to next section when I use mouse wheel after last slide. 'isEnd' method is working but not as I would like to.

It's scrolling page down in the same time when slide 9 is changing to slide 10 so I actually cant see what's there. I need to scroll back from section 3 to section 2 to see it. I want to call `$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();`

ONLY when I try to scroll after slide 10.

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do was to use "reachEnd".

```
on:{
            reachEnd: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
                },100)
            }
    }
```

After adding 'setTimeout', page doesn't scroll between slides 9 and 10 anymore :)

Comment: I've the same issue, where should I put the reachEnd and setTimeout ?